# Not able to connect node js express API deployed on AWS Lamda to AWS RDS(My SQL)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I deployed my node js express application on AWS Lamda and I am able to hit my API router method like get ,post etc .. but when I try to fetch data from amazon RDS it is returning 502 error in browser console and  without DB call the API returns hard-coded response well.
I tried to connect my API at initial stage and used following code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'rds end point',
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx',
    database: 'TestDb'
});

exports.handler = (event, context,callback) => { 
    context.callbackWaitForEmptyEventLoop=false;
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
        connection.query("select count(*) as count from Classes", function(error,result,fields) {
            connection.release();
            if(error) callback(error);
            else callback(null,result[0].count)
        })
    })
}
```

and at the LAMDA Console log I am getting below error instead of count

> "errorMessage": "2019-04-04T12:06:39.020Z 7ffa5ee4-4000-4254-82fc-27617eb9975a Task timed out after 5.01 seconds"

any one help me on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure RDS and the Lambda are in the same security group and your lambda has required permission

- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AWSLambdaFullAccess
- AmazonVPCFullAccess
- AWSLambdaExecute
- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole.
- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

If its in VPC create a new VPC Security group (for using in the lambda functions). and add inbound rule that accept ALL TRAFFIC for your VPC

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

> If your function needs network access to a resource like a relational
>   database that isn't accessible through AWS APIs or the internet,
>   configure it to connect to your VPC.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-permissions.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html
- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/master/iam-policies

Comment: Thanks a lot !! yes it was a security group issue , Now I am able to connect my RDS instance  from Lamda API.

Comment: If any answer is correct then mark else add ur answer and mark correct to help other ppl.